# cssSelector - How to identify div element by text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to identify the following div in a Liferay website. Liferay/primefaces dynamically changes the ID elements so we selenium testers cannot use them for our webdriver scripts.

I'm trying to find a cssSelector to identify this specific div:

```
<div class="ui-cell-editor-output" id="aui_3_4_0_1_1574">Test Org</div>
```

This css statement

```
div.ui-cell-editor-output
```

yields too many other hits to be usful.

Comment: try to use contextual information like `nth-child`, sibling selector adjacent selector and so on, it should be done

Comment: Or you could just add an extra class to the elements you wish to select: `class="ui-cell-editor-output MyVeryOwnSelectorClass"`

Comment: I'm QA not development so I can't add anything to the code :-(

Comment: @Nikos M I can go the nth-child method, but the list has about 50 names and they change often, so grabbing the name I want by index will eventually break when the list changes again...but maybe I have no other choice?

Comment: You most likely need javascript or jquery to achieve this, so I changed the tags for you